# qemu shared disk

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I try to create a disk that is shared between the host and VMs. For that I did following:

```
qemu-img  create -f raw src.img 15G
sudo mount -o loop ./src.img /media/cdrom
sudo losetup -l
sudo mkfs -txfs  /dev/loop0
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
sudo mkdir /mnt/src
sudo mount -o loop ./src.img /mnt/src
```

After that I add a disk to my VMs as following:

```
sudo virsh attach-disk vm1 /home/user/src.img vdb \
            --persistent  --cache none --shareable
```

Such that resulting config looks as following:

```
 <disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source file='/home/user/src.img'/>
  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
  <shareable/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x08' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

But when I modify the contents of the disk in either of the VMs or on the host, the change is not visible until I remount the disk.

How can I synchronize the views on the same disk?

Comment: I'm kinda curious, why are you trying to create a shared disk? Wouldn't something like an NFS share be easier?

Comment: I tried shared folder with 9p file system, but the performance with file system operations is very slow. Running make in the linux kernel probably takes 10x the normal time. I thought the disk may be better. Or I have to find another solution for my problem.

Comment: Oh no, a shared disk would probably be even slower since writes to the disk are not necessarily immediate, and reads from the disk may be cached. Network shares in general are not the fastest things necessarily in any case, but it's probably worth to invest in getting it implemented if it's bearable.

Comment: I have this exact problem sharing a small data disk between QEMU VMs and am very disappointed no answer was found.   @Zach, no network connectivity can be allowed in my case;

Comment: @Frobozz I guess the right thing to do is to use 9pfs. Or maybe you can share a file system over virtio.